# Fluctuations in estimator of $\min\{p,1-p\}$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-walk

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli with some parameter $1/2$. Let $\bar{X}_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. I am trying to show
$$\mathbb{E} \min\{\bar{X}_n,1-\bar{X}_n\} \ge \frac{1}{2} - C n^{-1/2},$$
but am having trouble.

It is clear that the left-hand side is $\le 1/2$, but it is not clear to me why the fluctuations are on the order of $n^{-1/2}$. Any hints or references would be appreciated!

I noticed that if we consider the one-dimensional random walk defined by $(2X_i-1)_{i=1}^n$, then $n(1-\min\{\bar{X}_n, 1-\bar{X}_n\})$ is the absolute distance of the random walk, but I am not sure how this could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show that
$$
\mathbb{E}[ \min\left(n\bar{X}, n(1-\bar{X})\right) ] \geq \frac{n}{2} - C\sqrt{n}
$$
for some constant $C>0$, which is equivalent to 
$$
\mathbb{E}[ \min\left(n\bar{X} - \frac{n}{2}, \frac{n}{2}-n\bar{X})\right) ] \geq  - C\sqrt{n}
$$
that is
$$
\mathbb{E}[ \lvert \mathbb{E}[S_n] - S_n \rvert ] \leq C\sqrt{n}
$$
where $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ follows a $\operatorname{Bin}(n,\frac{1}{2})$ distribution. Now, observe that [the variance of $S_n$ is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Variance)
$$
\mathbb{E}[ \left(S_n - \mathbb{E}[S_n] \right)^2 ] = \frac{n}{4}
$$
and by [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), the square function being convex,
$$
\mathbb{E}[ \lvert \mathbb{E}[S_n] - S_n \rvert ]^2 \leq \mathbb{E}[ \left(S_n - \mathbb{E}[S_n] \right)^2 ] = \frac{n}{4}.
$$

Comment: The intuition: "the standard deviation is more or less how we expect to deviate from the mean."

Comment: Thank you! What are some ways to tighten the step where you used Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @angryavian I don't think this particular approach will give you anything tighter. I can think of two other ideas (one a bit sketchier and handwavier, but simpler, than the other) which should get you a tight expression of the expectation, however: something like $$\frac{n}{2} - \sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi}} + o\left(\sqrt{n}\right)$$ provided I didn't mess up my computations.

Comment: @angryavian Please, consider accepting the answer if your question has been addressed. (If not, let me know how to improve my own answer to make it so.)